# Nodejs with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

Good evening guys. Please I'm new to `sql`. Trying to write a query to join 3 tables.

This is my result

I have a members table, a departments table and training table.

A member can be in more than one department. And can receive more than one training.

Please how do I relate this together. I tried joining the 3 tables but to my surprise the result outputs a member who is in 2 department twice eg

```
{
   Id: 6,
   name: Toyin,
   department: user
},
{
   Id: 6,
   name: Toyin,
   department: choir
}
```

This is my desired result

All I wanted is

```
{
   Id: 6,
   name: Toyin,
   department: [ user, choir]
}
```

I've been googling since like forever but still not getting it.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: How your tables looks like, what did you try? that not how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the inner join will work.

```sql
SELECT department2.id, department2.name, department2.department 
FROM department2 
INNER JOIN department1 ON department2.id = department1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table SCHEMA should be like this:

```
-USER Table
ID USER_NAME

-DEPARTMENT Table
ID DEPT_NAME

-TRAINING Table
ID TRAIN_NAME

-MEMBERSHIP Table
ID USER_ID DEPT_ID TRAIN_ID
```

**And you only need to add group by clause and JSON_ARRAYAGG aggregate method.**

```
SELECT USER.ID, USER.USER_NAME, JSON_ARRAYAGG(DEPT_NAME), JSON_ARRAYAGG(TRAIN_NAME)
FROM USER AS U
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP AS M ON M.USER_ID = U.ID
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS D ON M.DEPT_ID = D.ID
INNER JOIN TRAINING AS T ON M.TRAIN_ID = T.ID
WHERE USERID = 6
GROUP BY U.ID
```